# Why I am having troubles with the pipe operator?

Tags: r, dplyr, xts, magrittr

I have been using this code multiple times, it worked two weeks ago as usual, but now, when I run the first line, R does not change the dataset I don't know why. As soon as I remove the pipe operator the dataset changes but I can't filter by region.

```r
Covid19 <- read.csv("COVID19Cases_geoRegion.csv") %>%
    filter(geoRegion == "CH")

Cases    <- xts(Covid19[,3], order.by = as.Date(Covid19[,2]))
```

I also tried as follows but sill the same problem.

```r
Covid19 <- read.csv("https://www.covid19.admin.ch/api/data/20220216-i4f5f0q1/sources/COVID19Hosp_geoRegion.csv") %>%
 filter(geoRegion == "CH")
Hospital    <- xts(Covid19[,3], order.by = as.Date(Covid19[,2]))
```

I try to install again the package `dplyr` and also I tried with `magrittr` but it is not working, does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Without seeing your data, it's hard to diagnose an issue. I'd double check that the format of the data hasn't changed or anything.

Comment: I have edited the question with other code I am using so you can see the data, however, I am also having the same problem.

Comment: did you remember to run `library(dplyr)` before running these commands?

Comment: I did it, but nothing, I even tried it with magrittr

Comment: your code works fine for me.. after you do a clean install, restart with a fresh r session too. if it is still happening, see what is in your .Rprofile

Comment: If you post the error you are getting, that might also be helpful (in addition to the data or sample data)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are not getting any error. This can happen (?) if read operation fails and r is stuck. Tested what you shared.

Worked fine for me. though first i read the data in a seaprate df and then applied filters etc.

```
Covid19 <- read.csv("https://www.covid19.admin.ch/api/data/20220216-i4f5f0q1/sources/COVID19Hosp_geoRegion.csv")
```

Then

```
Covid19_CH <- Covid19%>%
  filter(geoRegion == "CH")
```

Can check full data:

```
Covid19%>%group_by(geoRegion)%>%
  summarise(N=n())
```

yields

```
# A tibble: 29 x 2
   geoRegion     N
   <chr>     <int>
 1 AG          724
 2 AI          724
 3 AR          724
 4 BE          724
 5 BL          724
 6 BS          724
 7 CH          724
 8 CHFL        724
 9 FL          724
10 FR          724
# ... with 19 more rows
```

#### surprising all GeoRegions has 724 records. Is that expected?

rest with xts is also working. You can test.
perhaps site was down! or you cna download teh csv file and read it locally (if that's an option)

Comment: Look, the first time I do it, it works, but then when I try to import another data in the same way. It gets stuck and the new dataset appears as "NULL" Because I am importing first cases, then hospitalizations, then deaths, etc. The first time I tried with cases, It works, but as soon as I tried to do it with the second or other it gets stucks, today I got this error.  *Error in Covid19a %>% Covid19a <- Covid19a %>%  : 
  could not find function "%>%<-*